# Storing Credentials in Credential Manager Service

Tags: c#, credentials

I have some credentials (username and a password), and I cannot figure out where to store them.

I heard about an application storing credentials in the Windows Credential Service, so I looked into this option. It seemed ideal. Just store sensitive information in a Windows Service, and not have to worry about storing them in your own registry key.

Unfortunately, I soon found out this was not so simple. The only help I found in MSDN was in C.  I then thought I must have been mistaken, but then I downloaded Cain, and saw an entry for decoding credential manager passwords.

Is there a way to use this feature in .NET? Please let me know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use interop to use the Credential Management API in .NET, but fortunately, somebody else has already done most of the hard work:

[Credential Management with the .NET Framework 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650605.aspx)

Comment: We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found. The URL may be misspelled or the page you're looking for is no longer available.

Comment: I think I fixed the link.