# using windows stored credentials in task scheduler windows 2012

Tags: powershell

[Get Cached Credentials in PowerShell from Windows 7 Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162604/get-cached-credentials-in-powershell-from-windows-7-credential-manager)

This shows how to use a logged in user credentials in a powershell script. Can the same process be used in Task scheduler, so that the entered username and pword for the task, is then used by script above to pull the stored credentials.

Using Windows 2012 Task Scheduler which is supposed to support this

Trying to lean away from any storing passwords in encrypted files.

Comment: I think the credentials would have to be placed in the credential manager but the account which the scheduled task is running as.  Did you try it and it didn't work?  Show us some code...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162604/get-cached-credentials-in-powershell-from-windows-7-credential-manager  code copied from here and if ($UseStoredCredential) {
 Import-Module MSOnline
 Import-Module .\Get-CredentialFromWindowsCredentialManager.psm1
 $creds = Get-StoredCredential $UseStoredCredential
 Connect-MSolService -Credential $creds
}   The scheduled task is then is started with a specific user and not the logged in user, but doesn't seem to connect

Comment: So I don't think it's using the schedule taks username and password to connect to the msol Tennant

Comment: My point was that the credentials that are in the credential manager are "by user", so if you placed them in there with the logged in user, they wouldn't be accessible if the scheduled task was running as a different user.