# How can I save network credentials to the Windows credentials cache/vault?

Tags: .net, credentials, networkcredentials, defaultnetworkcredentials, credentialscache

I am evaluating a 3rd party API [WebDAV.NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdav/index.html) for gaining access to SharePoint web folders. This API accepts the standard .Net network credentials and gives me two options:

```
ICredentials credential = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

and

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("[user]", "[password]");
```

If I connect to a network location (web folder) through Windows Explorer and authentication is required, Windows will automatically prompt me for a user name and password. I can then choose to remember the credentials and Windows will store them. Having done this, I can then use the first method above `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` to connect to the SharePoint web folder using this 3rd party API.

If however, I have not connected via Windows Explorer first, I could use the second option and provide a user name and password. However, these credentials do not get saved and do not get remembered.

I do not want to create my own mechanism for securing and storing these credentials. What I would like to do is prompt the user for his user name and password, create a network credential and store this to the Windows vault such that I can then turn around and use the first method `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` in connecting to the SharePoint web folder.

I basically would like to accomplish what Windows Explorer does, prompt for user name and password and then remember these.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Windows Vault".  You're thinking of how the Mac does things.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the following article on Windows 7 and you will see a window which says "Windows vault":
http://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-delete-saved-passwords-for-network-drives-in-windows/

Comment: you should look at a similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394721/storing-credentials-in-credential-manager-service

Comment: @Elan - Wow, did not even know that was there.  Still, it's a Windows 7 only feature, and I wouldn't trust it to stick around.