# Credential Locker - Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, security

Is there any option to use Credential locker in windows 7 in windows forms application? If it's not is there any other safe option to keep user credentials in win7/8 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve Credentials from Windows Credentials Store using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741424/retrieve-credentials-from-windows-credentials-store-using-c-sharp)

Comment: also possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2394721/327083