# Store Password for Third party login

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, password-protection

I am attempting to create a Soft-phone application in .NET C# and I've hit a wall when it comes to storing username and passwords in the application. I've thought about using SQL Server but since I'm not comfortable with storing the password in plaintext, I'm wondering what other options there are out there for me to accomplish this. Here are my constraints while developing this program:

- Must securely store username and password information
- It Cannot hash the password as the password needs to be sent to another server to authenticate with.
- Login information must persist between executions of the program. User should only have to save their login information once when they first run the program, then each time the program loads afterwards, it should automatically load the user info and authenticate with the server without prompting the user for the password again.
- Database is embedded within the application itself so it will be locally stored on the users computer.

This is the first time I've played with the idea of implementing a database function with C#. Any suggestions or recommendations are welcome. I'm more familiar with using SQL, but if there's an alternate database out there that would work better with what I'm trying to do, I'm willing to try it out.

Comment: Well, your first, second and last demands are mutually exclusive. You can not store a password in a safe way on the client's computer if it's not hashed. You can't even store it safely on your own server if it's not hashed.

Comment: Hashing is only a cheap way to compare passwords of current inputs (that you hashed/salted) against hashed/salted PW that you store in your db. You are probably more likely looking for some kind of reversable encryption of a password - think PGP. Let the user create a private/public key on first run, store it inside windows keystore on the client and use that to crypt/decrypt the userdata before storing it in a sql db. If the keypair is lost, so is the stored data - user has to recreate key and store it again. Tell the user to not distribute his private key though. This is only a deterrend.

Comment: Anybody that takes the computer and cracks the Windows-Login PW has access to the users pwstore as hes running as the user. Probably safer to let himinput his pw once per sessions. You could also simply implement your own crypto dll using prefab crypt/decrypt methods and some key you store in your sourcecode. Maybe distributed, not as const, maybe with replacements. Also a deterrend - if someone is sophisticated enough to reverseengeneer your storage of the key and the method used youre done in again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements you listed appear to be met by the Windows Credential Manager.  See [Storing Credentials in Credential Manager Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394721/storing-credentials-in-credential-manager-service)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i needed. Thankyou :-)